# What are the configurations or xml files to run a basic Spring MVC application?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I need to know the basic XML configuration files to put in my Web-inf folder, like web.XML, and where to write view resolver bean.

How do I register the controller?

When I run my application I get the error "could not open servlet context resource". What is servlet context resource and where do I mention it?

My web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<servlet>
<servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>
 jsp/index.jsp
 </welcome-file>


</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

My springmvc is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean name="/hello_world.html" class="springmvc.web.HelloWorldController"/>
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
<property name="prefix" value="/jsp/"/>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
 </bean>
</beans>
```

I have these two xml files only.

I know I need a spring configuration file too. I don't know what details I need to put in that.

Comment: Spring has very good documentation. You should probably read it.

Comment: @Max I like the Reference document (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/) too. But unfortunaly this document do not explain how to setup an application.

Answer (score 0):

If you use STS (Spring Tool Suite) then you can create a Spring Template Project.
(New Project/SpringSource Tool Suite/Spring Template Project/-Spring MVC Project)

This contains all the files you need to start.